# RxJS subscribe never executes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs, rxjs5

I would like to calculate and update my map's region every time the map's markers change. So I'm trying to create an observable from the map's markers and subscribe to it:

```
class Map extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => { })
    const markers$ = Observable.from(this.props.markers)
    markers$.subscribe(x => console.log('observable', x))
  }
```

Initially I am just console.logging the markers - but eventually I will want to run `getRegionForCoordinates` and then `this.props.updateRegion` whenever the markers change. Nothing ever logs to the console. What am I doing wrong? **`this.props.markers` is an empty array initially.**

**Map.js**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {
  Button,
  Container
} from 'native-base'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

import selectMarkers from './markers.selector'

import { updateRegion } from './map.action'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import { toggleMenu } from '../search-page/searchPage.action'
import mapStyle from './style'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  region: state.get('map').get('region'),
  markers: selectMarkers(state)
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onRegionChange: (region) => {
    dispatch(updateRegion(region))
  },
  onToggleMenuClick: () => {
    dispatch(toggleMenu())
  }
})



const getRegionForCoordinates = (points) => {
  // points should be an array of { latitude: X, longitude: Y }
  let minX, maxX, minY, maxY;

  // init first point
  ((point) => {
    minX = point.latitude
    maxX = point.latitude
    minY = point.longitude
    maxY = point.longitude
  })(points[0])

  // calculate rect
  points.map((point) => {
    minX = Math.min(minX, point.latitude)
    maxX = Math.max(maxX, point.latitude)
    minY = Math.min(minY, point.longitude)
    maxY = Math.max(maxY, point.longitude)
  })

  const midX = (minX + maxX) / 2
  const midY = (minY + maxY) / 2
  const deltaX = (maxX - minX)
  const deltaY = (maxY - minY)

  return {
    latitude: midX,
    longitude: midY,
    latitudeDelta: deltaX,
    longitudeDelta: deltaY
  }
}

class Map extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => { })
    const markers$ = Observable.from(this.props.markers)
    markers$.subscribe(x => console.log('observable', x))
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          region={this.props.region}
          onRegionChangeComplete={this.props.onRegionChange}
        >
          {
            this.props.markers.map(marker => {
              return (
                <MapView.Marker
                  coordinate={{ latitude: marker.latitude, longitude: marker.longitude }}
                  title={marker.name}
                />
              )
            })}
        </MapView>
        <Button
          small
          icon
          style={mapStyle.toggleMenuButton}
          onPress={() => this.props.onToggleMenuClick()}>
          <Icon name="sliders" size={20} color="#FFFFFF" />
        </Button>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

Map.contextTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object
}

Map.propTypes = {
  region: React.PropTypes.shape({
    latitude: React.PropTypes.number,
    longitude: React.PropTypes.number,
    latitudeDelta: React.PropTypes.number,
    longitudeDelta: React.PropTypes.number
  }).isRequired,
  onRegionChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onToggleMenuClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  markers: React.PropTypes.array
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Map)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    zIndex: -1
  }
})
```

**markers.selector.js**

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'


const searchResultsSelector = state => {
  return state.get('searchResults')
}

const selectMarkers = createSelector(
  searchResultsSelector,
  (searchResults) => {
    const shops = searchResults ? searchResults.map(result => {
      return result.shops.map(shop => {
        return {
          id: shop.f1,
          name: shop.f2,
          latitude: shop.f4,
          longitude: shop.f3
        }
      })
    }) : searchResults
    const shopIds = []
    const flattenedShops = [].concat.apply([], shops)
    const uniqueShops = flattenedShops.map(shop => {
      if (!shopIds.includes(shop.id)) {
        shopIds.push(shop.id)
        return shop
      }
    })
    const finalMarkers = uniqueShops.filter(n => n != undefined)
    return finalMarkers
  }
)

export default selectMarkers
```

Comment: The observable is created from the **current** value of `this.prop.markers` when `Observable.from` is called. `Observable.from` does not set up any dynamic link from the array to the observable. You'll need to do something like `send` to a `Subject` when `this.props.markers` changes.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks. I'm really struggling to implement the subject. I cannot get it to fire `next()` when the `props.markers` changes

Comment: There is no notion in JS of "watching" or "observing" some variable or array. You'll have to arrange to know when `this.props.markers` changes, or is changed, or might have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]
below is the solution using rx observables, but quickly after posting it, I was thinking: **are you sure you need the power of `Observables` to achieve what you want?**

I think you should consider only using the `componentWillReceiveProps` which is the React way to observe changes. It might very well suit you needs, I think.
You can totally trigger a `getRegionForCoordinates` and `this.props.updateRegion` in this callback without the need of any observable.
[END EDIT]

I see what you are trying to achieve. First, you have to understand that `Observable.from` only takes a single object/value and then ignores any change made to the initial object.

```
const value = [1]
const obs$ = Observable.from(arr)
obs$.subscribe(console.log.bind(console)) // < this will only print once
value.push(2); // < this will be ignored and wont fire anything
```

But, hopefully for you, there is a way to tell `React` "warn me when properties change". And that's exactly what you want. You want to catch any change made to the `this.props.markers` and feed it to your observable.

We are going to use Rect's `componentWillReceiveProps` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops to do that

First thing we need to do, is to keep a reference to the `marker$` (so it can be accessed in another method:

```
componentDidMount() {
  //...
  this.markers$ = new Observable.Subject()
  //you can subscribe here to this observable
  this.markers$.next(this.props.markers)
}
```

And we will also need to implement the `componentWillReceiveProps` that will feed our `markers$`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.markers$.next(nextProps.markers)
}
```

And now, this will trigger a `subscribe` call on your `markers$`.

Comment: Thanks. You are probably right that I don't need an observable. But theoretically, to teach me a bit of RxJS, in the solution in your answer with an observable, where would I call `getRegionForCoordinates` and then `this.props.updateRegion`? Would I add a subscribe to `this.markers$` in `componentDidMount`? similar to this but calling my two functions? `.subscribe({
  next: x => console.log('got value ' + x),
  error: err => console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('done'),
});`

Comment: Exactly, you would add a `subscribe` in the `componentDidMount` and call `getRegionForCoordinates` and `this.props.updateRegion` from there. Warning, if you do not use arrow functions for the subscribe (or next) callback, you will be to bind the callback to `this` else it won't be defined in the callback (`markers$.subscribe(function callback() { /*..*/ }.bind(this))`)